# VS2015 The type name does not exist in the type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I've got the following situation: A WCF service is running and by using "add service reference" the client code is generated.

```
namespace Delivery.PublishingService {

  [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="PublishingService.IPublish", CallbackContract=typeof(Delivery.PublishingService.IPublishCallback))]
  public interface IPublish {}
```

It generates the namespace Delivery.PublishingService as usual and later the types are referenced by fully qualified names like "Delivery.PublishingService.IPublishCallback".

But Visual Studio 2015 throws an error: 
The type name 'PublishingService' does not exist in the type 'Delivery'

But as you can see above, the code is **inside** the namespace already. This should compile really.
Is this a bug in VS 2015 or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using that results in this error?

Comment: Any chance you have a class in your project called "delivery"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in the end by simply using another name. Somehow the name Delivery was not possible to use even though it was never used in the project. But it was a class in another project in the solution, maybe that was the problem